# $A$ and $B$ conjugacy

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that the matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ are not $\mathbb{Z}$ conjugate (there exists no matrix $S\in\mathbb{GL}_{2x2}(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $SAS^{-1}=B.$ Show that this isn't the case if we consider $\mathbb{Q}$ conjugacy.

**$\mathbb{Z}$ conjugacy:** Suppose $\exists$ such an $S=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. Then since det$(S)=\pm 1$, we have $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. This implies:

$ad=\pm1$

$ab=0$

$cd=1/2$

$cb=0$.

But $cd=1/2$ is a contradiction, since $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $A$ and $B$ are not $\mathbb{Z}$ conjugate.

**$\mathbb{Q}$ conjugacy:** Using the relations above, we find that $S=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1/2&0\end{pmatrix}$ is an appropriate matrix.

Does this look alright?

Comment: Think: Is your matrix S invertible?

Comment: Oops, I meant to put $S=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1/2&1\end{pmatrix}.$ :)

Comment: Do you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes, are you referring the the eigenvalues of $S$? It has one eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ of multiplicity two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for both looks fine (though difficult to generalize to bigger $n \times n$ matrices).  Indeed, we find that
$$
SAS^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{1&0\\1/2&1}
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&0}
\pmatrix{1&0\\-1/2&1} = 
\pmatrix{2&0\\1&0}
$$